# Resize Background Image

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

Hi guys I want to resize an Image background of a Style, I have an Image View that uses the style and shows the background image

Style:

```
 <style name="Background">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/img_background</item>
    </style>
```

So I have the "img_background", and it's size it's about 1920*1080, I want to resize it pefectly so it fits all devices sizes, How can make it resize automatically depending on the screen sizes?, Beacuse It doesn't work
It doesn't show the image properly is way off and is not resized properly to fit the screen.

I have a LinearLayout that has the style and then the Image view inside it. It doesn't fit the 1920*1080 properly, for example in a 800*480 resolution it is cropped off and not neatly resized

```
<LinearLayout

            style="@style/Background"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            >





            <ImageView

                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                android:src="@drawable/img_background"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: use :
 android:layout_width="match_parent" and 
android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Do you want it only to be 50dp high?

Comment: Yes My Imageview is small, I want the width to be correctly resized, the image is a Banner that's really long in Width,

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style from the `LinearLayout`

Put this as your imageView:

```
<ImageView
  android:contentDescription="@null"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:clickable="false"
  android:paddingLeft="15dip"
  android:scaleType="centerInside"
  android:src="@drawable/img_background" />
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work, I am using a Linear Layout applying that the style and then putting the ImageView Inside that. Like this check the OP for update

Answer (score 0):

Change layout_width and layout_height your xml

```
<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
```

Comment: Hi that didn't work, check the OP I update it with more info Thanks